# MaxModelValidationErrors = 1 in .NET Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an object that implements the `IValidatableObject` interface and inside "AddControllers" (Startup.cs), I set the `MaxModelValidationErrors` property to 1. The problem is that when I reach the limit of errors, I can't get the custom error that I throw, I only get `"The maximum number of allowed model errors has been reached"`. I need this because I have validations on a database and I don't want to do unnecessary queries. Is it possible to fix this using `ValidationResult ("MY_ERROR")`? Thanks.

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext){

    ...
    yield return new ValidationResult("MY_ERROR");
    ...

}
```

[image]

Without `MaxModelValidationErrors`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the `MaxModelValidationErrors` property to 2.

When it is 1,it will stop when getting one error,and add Exception `The maximum number of allowed model errors has been reached`to ModelState,it count as an error,whatever the error is from `built-in attributes`,or `custom attributes`,or `IValidatableObject`.So you cannot get your own error message.It is by design.

Comment: Hi, I don't think this is the solution, if I have 2 errors, I would have the same problem :(